# handling interruptions in insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm processing(aggregating) a log file, and this is my process:

1. convert binary file to array of strings
2. start upsert at line `$n` (taken from a process_log record)
3. handle individual strings
4. parse string as object
5. insert object into various rollups
6. update `$n` record in process_log

The problem I have, however rare it may be, that when there is any interruption at any point and it will very likely happen during step 5. Meaning, that it will update the rollup but not the process_log record, and when it starts again it will process the last line twice.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is it possible to upsert to several collections at once and would that resolve the problem, and a way to do so with mongoose?